# How to Set X Domain to Nested Value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My chart is not working yet, but that isn't important, as I'm going one element at a time. As posted in my last question, here is the data I'm working with:

```
{
    "chartData":[
        {
            "vId":307,
            "vNm":"Alejandro Rivera Ulloa",
            "values":[
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":37,"id":132},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":38,"id":133},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":33,"id":134}
            ]
        },
        {
            "vId":308,
            "vNm": "Daniel Torres",
            "values": [
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":41,"id":135},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":41,"id":136},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":41,"id":137}
            ]
        },
        {
            "vId":309,
            "vNm": "Pablo Alvarez Garcia",
            "values":[
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":16,"id":138},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":17,"id":139},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":14,"id":140}
            ]
        },
        {
            "vId":391,
            "vNm":"Janette Avalos de Conte",
            "values":[
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":28.5,"id":141},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":29,"id":142},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":27.5,"id":143}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything is fine there and my code loads the data just fine. This is the foreach that allows me to get everything everywhere (to put it simply):

```
data.chartData.forEach(function(kv){
    var vNmName = kv.vNm;
    var vIdName = kv.vId;
    kv.values.forEach(function(d){
        d.period = d.period;
        d.id = d.id;
        d.amount = +d.amount; 
        d.vNm = vNmName;
        d.vId = vIdName;
    });
});
```

So here's what I need. My X domain is displaying incorrectly and I know why. This is the line of code:

```
x.domain(data.chartData[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.period; }));
```

And this line gives me just the periods, exactly what it's supposed to do, as it only accesses the first element of chartData. Here's a JSFiddle with all of the code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfmyxyn8/)

Comment: So, for the x domain to display correctly, what would need to be different - I don't understand the problem.

Comment: The problem is I need ALL of the periods to show up, not just three from the first element. @SamH.

Comment: all the periods are the same - how can you tell that it's not getting all of them?

Comment: I tried it with different values, and I get the same result. Also, this is just the beginning. At some point I will be changing most of this graph. This is just a proof of concept for me @SamH. In other words. It just displays the values of the first bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, how about:

```
var xDomain = []
data.forEach(function(d){
    d.values.forEach(function(v){
        if (xDomain.indexOf(v.period) === -1){
            xDomain.push(v.period);
        }
    });
});
xDomain.sort();
x.domain(xDomain);
```

The ticks display `NAN` because you used an incorrect format:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0);
    //.tickFormat(d3.format("d")); //<-- this says convert to integer, your string dates don't convert to integer
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfmyxyn8/1/).

Comment: You're the best. Thanks a bunch.